# Getting data from iframe with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, iframe, input, field

I have a simple page with iframe. In this frame there are a three input fields, which user fill in. How to get this data in every input field with js?

Here is **js**:

`<script type="text/javascript"> var ticket = window.frames[0].document.getElementById('ticket').ticket; alert(ticket); </script>`

And i have inside frame:

`<input type='text' name='ticket' id='ticket'...`

Nothing happens when I fill all 3 inputfield and press ok. How to save this data, which filled in this input fields to .txt file, than I can grab this txt by php and fill into database.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not convinced that iframes are accessible via the `window.frames` property.  You could try something like this:

```
var frame = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0]
  , form = frame.contentDocument.forms[0];
alert("OK: ticket=" + form.ticket.value);
```

Storing the form values in the database is another issue entirely.  It might be easiest to avoid JavaScript entirely and simply make the form within the iframe perform a POST to your own PHP handler which can save the contents as needed.

Answer (score 0):

I spent a lot of time trying to figure out how to exchange data from between text boxes in two Iframes. (I am the author of both iframes). After a lot of wasted time and looking for solutions on the internet the solution was, of course, incredible easy. Everyone on the internet is doing **MUCH** more complicated things. For those of you who want to do something simple!

I have a main page with two Iframes (ID = `ifr1` and `ifr2`). Each frame had a text box (ID = `tb1` (in `ifr1`)). In javascript you can get the contents of `tb1` in iframe `ifr2` by simply using

`parent.ifr1.tb1.value` or `parent.ifr1.document.getElementByID(‘tb1’).value.`

To change the value, obviously"

`parent.ifr1.tb1.value=”whatever”` or  `parent.ifr1.document.getElementByID(‘tb1’).value=”whatever”`

You can also access a variable from `ifr1` from `ifr2` by using

`parent.ifr1.var_in_ifr1` where `var_in_ifr1` is defined in the script of `ifr1`

`var var_in_ifr1=”whatever”`